# Outputting formatted text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bots, discord

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Discord Bot to post a message with weird text formatting. I want it to look like:

Ḥ̵̏͂È̷̞Ḻ̵̼̾Ḷ̴̥̪̊̃͘Ȍ̵̙̟̓͋ ̴̰̕W̵̭̾̅͑Ö̴̤́͘R̴̫̞͛́̓Ļ̸͇͑͝D̶̡͇̅̏

I can convert this into HTML but I have no idea how to get my bot to read that and output it as text into Discord. I've tried having it read everything as ASCII but then it just spits up a bunch of blank squares and it doesn't space anything correctly.

Any ideas here? I'm at a loss.

Comment: That is text without any special formatting. It's an artistic use of the typographic elements built into Unicode, specifically 'combining "characters"'. HTML uses Unicode. ASCII doesn't have anything to do with anything. Do you mean numeric character entity references? Perhaps your framework disallows those characters. Perhaps it's just your test method (e.g., "debugging output"). As you can see it works fine here. JavaScript uses the UTF-16 character encoding of Unicode.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to forgive me I'm not super well versed in this. Any ideas on how to get that output in js?

Comment: In JavaScript, literal strings use a pair of single or double quote characters.

Comment: So if I just copy and paste it into my code a la 

    message: "hello world"

It should work?

Comment: In general, yes, but I'm not familiar with Discord Bot. (Post an answer if you figure it out. You can accept it, too, when you think it's the best among the sufficient answers.)